# Wearing shirts with a corporate logo from former employer

Tags: professionalism, united-states, dress-code

In the course of my career as an engineer, working for a variety of employers, I have collected a variety of business casual shirts (both polo and button down) with the company logo of my employer at the time. While a few of the shirts have gotten dirty or worn beyond what's acceptable in an office environment, most of them are still in good condition and I'd like to wear them to work on occasion. Is that likely to have negative consequences? If so, what should I do with these shirts?

I will add that none of the companies I've worked for are competitors of my current employer, so it's not like I'm working at Ford and wearing a shirt with a GM logo.

Comment: This is difficult to answer because it depends on your specific workplace, and is largely opinion-based. I would not think wearing these shirts would be a problem, but it's best to ask co-workers or your manager.

Comment: I would advise against it.  While it's not like wearing a Coke shirt to Pepsi headquarters, it could still be seen as disrespectful to your current employer.

Comment: Perhaps I should add that not only are the different companies not competitors, they aren't even in the same industry. Think Oil & Gas vs. Medical Device vs. Automotive

Comment: Personally I always consider shirts from former employers as good shirts to paint in. Does your living room need painting?

Comment: Would need specifics for your office.   Wear the shirts on the weekend is not an option?

Comment: Office is business casual, so khakis and a collared shirt. My typical dress code on the weekend is jeans and t shirts, so not really.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's up to you. If they're not competitors then it's much like wearing a cap with a sports logo or similar. I often wear a Batman T-shirt.

Personally I rarely wear them because I wear plain clothing to work, logo's and bells and whistles I wear after hours as casual clothes in order to spare my work clothing from wear and tear and I'm happy to have them for that reason. But I don't see a problem with you wearing them unless your workplace has a policy or dresscode that makes it inappropriate.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the circumstances but in general it's not a good idea.

Your are in essence expressing endorsement and appreciation for your former employer and you are running free advertising for them. Many people will interpret this as "so he likes company XXX better than us".

It can be okay if the other employer is highly regarded and well liked in your current company. You can wear an Apple shirt, if the whole office is an Apple Fan Boy club.

Still, if in doubt, don't do it.